# single quotes in stored procedure update MYSQL

Tags: mysql, web-services, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm trying a simple update using a stored proc using data from a web service but it is failing saying Unknown column 'USERNAME' in 'field list' due to the single quotes not being recognised in the stored proc.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE PYBUsers set IsMember = 1 where user = p_user;
END
```

as you can see the p_user is supplied but the web service and does not have single quotes so gets rejected.  I have also tried

```
SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE PYBUsers set IsMember = 1 where user = \'', p_user, '''');
```

and

```
SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE PYBUsers set IsMember = 1 where user = ', "'",p_user,"'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

but no luck.  is there an easy solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Try SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE PYBUsers set IsMember = 1 where user = ''', p_user, ''''); - '' gives a single quote character.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, same error, and removed one of the ' from each side after it was run.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE PYBUsers set IsMember = 1 where user = ''',p_user,'''');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

To add a single quotes into a string you have to put two single quotes together i.e.
'This is Dan''s string; Single quote is inserted between the n and s

''''; this one is a little awkward to read, but here goes.  The first quote opens the string, the next two quotes generate a single quote in the string.  The final quote closes the string.

```
INSERT INTO myTable values ('''')
```

The above would result in one quote being stored in the table